# MySQL update is running slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

The following query:

```
 UPDATE `zydushr`.`performance`  AS a1 , `zydusquiz`.`performance` AS a2 
 SET a1.`Sales` = a2.`AchievementHQ` WHERE a1.`EmpNo` = a2.`EmpNo` 
 AND a1.`Month` = a2.`Month` AND a1.`Year` = a2.`Year` ;
```

is running very slowly. How can I speed it up?

Note: i have already created the indexes.

Comment: Your question asks about sql server but your tags include mysql, which is it?

Comment: How big are the a1 and a2 tables?

Comment: its can more than 447949 records

Comment: How many indexes do you have in the table `a1`?  Did you try to rebuild you indexes? Can you upload the query plan when you run that query?

Comment: how i can rebuild to it.. i have created at table creation time ... one time only ..

Comment: it has 6 index in both side

Comment: To rebuild the indexes in your `a1` table.  In SQL Management Studio, you have to go to the indexes in your a1 table, right click on it and click on the  `rebuild indexes` option.  Be careful with this because if you are working in a production server this can cause performance problems while you run the rebuilding. (same for `a2`)

Comment: i have only 4 option in index ... create index, edit index drop index, manage index

Comment: and sir .. i have use SQL YOG (MySQL manager)

Comment: MySQL "never" needs its tables "rebuilt".  Perhaps @CrApHeR comment was aimed at some other engine?

Comment: Yes @RickJames, because the previous title was related to SQL Server and not to MySql.  I changed the title to the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
`zydushr`.`performance`  AS a1 
JOIN `zydusquiz`.`performance` AS a2 
ON a1.`EmpNo` = a2.`EmpNo` 
 AND a1.`Month` = a2.`Month` 
 AND a1.`Year` = a2.`Year` 
SET a1.`Sales` = a2.`AchievementHQ`
```

Comment: Good eye on the cross join he was using.

Comment: its also takes same time as above ... i have run the query but still its running phase...

Comment: It was not a cross join -- see the `WHERE` clause.  (Still, `JOIN...ON` is better form.)

Answer (score 0):

For speed, you need a *composite* index:

```
INDEX(emp_no, year, month)
```

That is *not* the same as `INDEX(emp_no), INDEX(year), INDEX(month)`.

It is usually bad practice to have separate columns for date and time components.